# mailspring isn't found in application search

Tags: snap

I installed mailspring using snap. It installed fine, I can open it via the terminal, but for some reason it won't show up when I search for it in all applications (i.e. pressing super key and typing mailspring). It just isn't there.

I already tried adding /snap/bin to path with `export PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin"`, which does what it's supposed to. After I restart the terminal and again check `echo $PATH`, snap/bin is gone.

Comment: Welcome! You have to add  `export PATH...` permanently say in the file `~/.profile`

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do with ~/.profile?

Comment: Open the file `~/.profile` for example with gedit and add at the bottom `export PATH="$PATH:/snap/bin"`.

Comment: That worked, thank you!